# difference between a series of columns similar to cumsum

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the difference between a series of columns in Pandas. The number fo columns changes. The input and output looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d={'A':[1,2,3,4],\
'B':[2,3,6,1],\
'C':([6,5,4,1]),\
'D':[1,2,3,4]}

pd.DataFrame(data=d)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  6  1
1  2  3  5  2
2  3  6  4  3
3  4  1  1  4
```

```
o={'B':[1,1,3,-3],\
   'C':[4,2,-2,0],\
   'D':[-5,-3,-1,3]}
pd.DataFrame(data=o)

   B  C  D
0  1  4 -5
1  1  2 -3
2  3 -2 -1
3 -3  0  3
```

Is there a solution similar to the pandas cumsum or do I need to write a series of loops ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a column-wise diff with [**`DataFrame.diff`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
df.diff(axis=1).iloc[:, 1:]

     B    C    D
0  1.0  4.0 -5.0
1  1.0  2.0 -3.0
2  3.0 -2.0 -1.0
3 -3.0  0.0  3.0
```

---

```
df.diff(axis=1).dropna(how='all', axis=1).astype(int)

   B  C  D
0  1  4 -5
1  1  2 -3
2  3 -2 -1
3 -3  0  3
```